# JQM 1.4.1: The new event 'pagecontainershow'

Tags: jquery-mobile

I got confused with JQM changes:

As you may know JQM deprecated the event:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', '#MyPage', function(){
```

and replaced it by:

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function (e, ui) {
```

However this new event is not attached to an specific page as the previous was. Nevertheless, the event:

```
$(document).on('pagecreate', '#MyPage', function(){
```

is still attached to a specific page, and i think other pages events are still attached to specific pages.

MY QUESTION IS:

The fact that some events are attached to pages and other no, makes the framework very confusing. Should'nt be better to standarized all events as the version 1.3 was in which all were attached to pages?

Will the event 'pagecreate' and all pages events be dettached to pages in the future as 'pageshow' is now in version 1.4.1

Can someone please explain how events work in 1.4.1

Thanks

Comment: The only event that can be attached to a specific page is `pahecreate`.

Comment: I have posted an issue on GitHub. They're working on updating api. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6865

Answer (score 2):

I just resolved the issue of pagecontainershow not being able to attach to a PAGE by using a "switch case" sentence like this:

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function (e, ui) {

var ThisPage = $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('getActivePage').attr('id');

  switch(ThisPage){

    case 'Page1':

    case 'Page2':

    case 'Page3':


etc....
```

However my concern is that if they modify the framework to support (back again) the event attached to pages, then I should be doing rework and rework.

Comment: Yup, you're absolutely right.  Nice solution.  I'm beginning to get really annoyed reading through the new API and finding all these deprecated events that are not backwards compatible with 1.4.1.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code based on the previous response I wrote that made my converting JQM 1.3 code in my HTML files easier after finding that the issue about this that Omar posted was closed as not a bug:

```
function setPageContainerHandlers(){
    function getPageContainerEventHandler(action){
        var handler = function(e, ui){
            var id = $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('getActivePage').attr('id');
            var f = window.page_handlers[action]['#' + id];
            if ('function' == typeof f){
                f(e, ui);
            }
        }

        return handler;
    }

    var events = ['pagecontainershow', 'pagecontainerhide', 'pagecontainerbeforeload', 'pagecontainerbeforeshow', 'pagecontainerload', 'pagecontainerloadfailed', 'pagecontainerchangefailed'];
    var actions = ['pageshow', 'pagehide', 'pagebeforeload', 'pagebeforeshow', 'pageload', 'pageloadfailed', 'pagechangefailed']

    for(var i = 0; i < events.length; i++){
        var handler = getPageContainerEventHandler(actions[i]);
        $(document).on(events[i], handler);
        window.page_container_handlers[events[i]] = handler;
        window.page_handlers[actions[i]] = {};
    }
}

function registerPageHandler(id, action, handler){
    window.page_handlers[action][id] = handler;
}
```

Then, as long as `setPageContainerHandlers()` is called in a `<script>` tag in the document head,

`$("#results").on("pagebeforeshow", initResults);`

becomes

`registerPageHandler("#results", "pagebeforeshow", initResults);`.

Answer (score 0):

How about just checking for the current page and exit the event if not the one you want?
That way, you can use separate functions as "normal".

```
$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function (e, ui) {
    if (ui.toPage[0].id != "YOUR_PAGE_1") return;

    //Do you stuff for YOUR_PAGE_1 here
});

$(document).on('pagecontainershow', function (e, ui) {
    if (ui.toPage[0].id != "YOUR_PAGE_2") return;

    //Do you stuff for YOUR_PAGE_2 here
});
```