# Getting computed (not CSS) width() in jquery-mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a div id="XYZ" with CSS specified width: 37%;

I then wish to use the px width of this div to set other widths, but I can only access the given css% value and not the computed px width of the div in the DOM. What am I doing wrong?

```
$( document ).on( "pagecreate", "#page", function( event ) {

        var divWidth = $("#XYZ").width();
        console.log('div XYZ width is ' + divWidth); 

});
```

It outputs 37. Which is the css % value, but jquery width() SHOULD give me the computed width in px, shouldn-t it?

I was thinking that maybe the problem is that I-m asking at 'pagecreate' (same result in deprecated 'pageinit').

How can I get the computed width of the div?

Comment: i think this link help you

SEE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305707/assigned-width-in-percentage-but-want-to-get-it-in-pixels

Comment: @vivek, thx but.. your link tells me that what i said in the question, what jquery width() should do. Now why is it not working in jquery-mobile?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/width/

Comment: @vivek, you are not telling me anything. Why do you think I need to read the api again? What am I not seeing?

Comment: use `pagecontainershow` (if you're using jQM 1.4) event to get computed width. At `pagecreate` event, elements are invisible and still page has not taken full shape.

Comment: @Omar, thanks, I have to say the wording in the JQM documentation led me to think that computed widths would be possible, after reading about pagecontainershow (eg the api and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21801315/jqm-1-4-1-the-new-event-pagecontainershow ) not being page specific and with little tutorials to lead the way, I-m going to side step my problem and uses window width... If you would like to answer the question I will accept though! (please include any extra info, ideas etc!)

Comment: FROM THE DOCUMENTATION::::: pagecreate eventversion added: 1.0
Description: Triggered when the page has been created in the DOM (via ajax or other) and after all widgets have had an opportunity to enhance the contained markup. ::::::: So shouldn-t it give computed pixels??

Comment: Page is created but still hidden, not visible at this stage. It's visible when `pagecontainershow` fires. http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/

Comment: @Omar, great link! Very nice graphical and text breakdown!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pagecreate` to retrieve actual `.width()`, `.height()`, `.offest()`, etc., won't return the computed value since *page* and *elements* within it are are all hidden.

To retrieve such data, you need to use `pagecontainertransition` when transition between previous page and next page is complete, or `pagecontainerhide` when previous page is completely hidden, or `pagecontainershow` when next page is completely visible.

However, note that those events can't be attached to a specific page. As of jQM 1.4, "page events" are replaced with "[PageContainer Events](http://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/03/26/jquery-mobile-page-events/)". Thus, - *unfortunately* - you ought to use `if` statement or `switch/case`.

```
$( document ).on( "pagecontainershow" , function( event, ui ) {
  var divWidth = $( "#XYZ" ).width();
  console.log('div XYZ width is ' + divWidth);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**getComputedStyle**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle)

> The Window.getComputedStyle() method gives the values of all the CSS properties of an element after applying the active stylesheets and resolving any basic computation those values may contain.

Use

```
var divWidth = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle($("#XYZ")[0], null).width;
```

Or

```
var divWidth = window.getComputedStyle($("#XYZ")[0], null).width;
```

Comment: THANKS, however I am still getting the 37% value for both. The problem may well lie with JQM order of page events.